# How to deploy ASPNET Core site to Azure Linux Web App (no container)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a web app, and I've setup VSTS to create a package in build, and then deploy it using release management.

It puts all of the result in the wwwroot of the site if I look at it in ftp so I get:

/site/wwwroot/
                /wwroot
                /

This doesn't run and I get a 404 error.

If I use the URL and go say /wwwroot/images/ it returns it just fine.

The app is set to use .net core and I'm doing a self-contained package.

How do I get VSTS release to put the files in the right place and what is the right place ? I can't find any documentation on this anywhere. Everything is to do with Windows.

Also, what linux target should the dotnet application be set to for self-contained? I have it using ubuntu but I'm sure that's wrong and it's something else.

Comment: Can you share the detail build and release log here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use Azure App Service Deploy task with 4.* (preview) version instead, and deploy again:

[image]

Comment: I tried that. No change. Files are still in the /wwwroot on ftp and it still gives 404 errors.  I tried cleaning it out and redeploying as well with no luck. Does it matter that it's being deployed from a windows agent?  Also, does it matter that it's a self-contained ASPNET core 2.1 site targeting Ubuntu? (Which should it target for Azure Linux?)

Comment: If you have self-contained asp.net core site, you can refer the document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x, or the blog https://www.tonyranieri.com/blog/2017/10/27/Hosting-.Net-Core-On-Linux/.

Comment: Thanks... I guess, but neither one of these tells me how to setup VSTS to properly deploy to App Service Linux and have it work properly the way it should.  This is 101 stuff that should either just work, or have full documentation from MS.

Comment: Can you share the detail release logs to RM_Customer_Queries@microsoft.com? Or you can create a new issue in github (https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues).

Comment: Will do.  Thanks.

Comment: We ultimately gave up on this and are using docker containers now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I responded here. Essentially you need to have a startup command pointing to your DLL because Dev Ops deploys the package in a different way than VS.

[Deploying .Net Core to Linux WebApps on Azure with DevOps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54618574/deploying-net-core-to-linux-webapps-on-azure-with-devops/56397010#56397010)